# HTML to PDF pages bottom margin grows larger with every page

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, pdf-generation

I'm trying to convert HTML to PDF on iOS.  The first page always looks fine, but then every page after that stops printing to the page higher and higher up.  It appears as if the bottom margin is mysteriously growing.  I have dug through it numerous times and can't locate what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the primary method where I think the problem is.

```
- (NSData*) printToPDF
{
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData( pdfData, CGRectZero, nil );

    [self prepareForDrawingPages: NSMakeRange(0, self.numberOfPages)];

    CGRect bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds();

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < self.numberOfPages ; i++ )
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

        [self drawPageAtIndex: i inRect: bounds];
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    return pdfData;
}
```

You can also see the entire thing here.

[iOS-htmltopdf](https://github.com/iclems/iOS-htmltopdf/blob/master/NDHTMLtoPDF.m)

Comment: try using UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pageSize, nil);

Comment: Tried that, the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You `A4 size` is `incorrect`. As a result margin increases

```
#define kPaperSizeA4 CGSizeMake(595.2,841.8
```

Comment: Wow; digging through some old posts there!  This was a bug in the library I was using at the time that has since been fixed. The kPaperSizeA4 is defined within the library, not within my project.  At the time it was being defined as `CGSizeMake(595, 841)` so the imprecision built up over time as the page number grew.